# Guess the Number In C++

Tags: c++, c++17, number-guessing-game

Mind that this is my first actual program in C++ and I tried to prepare for any possible input.  Also the reason I included `static_cast<void>(generator(range))` is to throw away the first random value because I read on [LearnCpp.com](https://learncpp.com) that throwing away the first is a common practice to produce more random results.  Anyways here is the code, all suggestions are welcome.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <random>

bool validateInput(int input)
{
    using namespace std;

    if (1 <= input && input <= 100)
        return true;
    else if (!input)
        return false;
    else
        return false;
}

int generateRandomNumber()
{
    std::random_device dev;
    std::mt19937_64 range(dev());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937_64::result_type> generator(1, 100);
    static_cast<void>(generator(range));
    return static_cast<int>(generator(range));
}

bool placement(int input, int target)
{
    using namespace std;
    if (input > target)
    {
        cout << "Guess is too high.";
        return false;
    }

    else if (input < target)
    {
        cout << "Guess is too low.";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Guess is correct!";
        return true;
    }
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "You have 7 guesses to guess what number I am thinking of between 1 and 100.\n";
    int winning_num{ generateRandomNumber() };
    static int tries{ 1 };
    do
    {
        int num;
        cout << "\nGuess#" << tries << ": Enter a number -> ";
        cin >> num;
        if (!cin)
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            continue;
        }

        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        
        if (validateInput(num))
            ;
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (!placement(num, winning_num))
        {
            cout << "\nIncorrect!\n";
            ++tries;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nCorrect!\n";
            exit(0);
        }

    }
    while (tries <= 7);
    cout << "\nYou did not guess the number in the alloted amount of guesses :(\nTry Again!\n";


}
```

Comment: `else if (!input) return false; else return false;` It should be `return false;` after the if and that's all, both else return the same value and the if returns a value so you can omit the else and go `return` instead.

Comment: Also, in the first function it is unnecessary to place `using namespace std` since you aren't calling anything within `std`

Comment: `if (validateInput(num)); else { continue; }` is equivalent to write `if (!validateInput(num)) continue;` because `!` is the not operator. It inverts `true` to `false` and `false` to `true`

Comment: @Miguel Avila Yeah that is a good point, I should’ve thought of that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @anki If you read the description up above, it is a common practice to throw away the first value of a random number generator, which that line of code does.

Comment: @Miguel Avila For your first comment you’re absolutely correct, I ran into some problems with my code and i added that ‘else if’ statement to try something else and I forgot to remove it.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question after receiving answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Mast Alright sorry I did not know, I just forgot to remove a useless line before uploading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like that your code (read functions) follows [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

And also that you've put the number comparison code in a separate function unlike

- [User guesses the number generated by computer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/247749/205955)
- [Computer tries to guess your inputted number](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/247383/205955)

And also that you use `static_cast`. All are good coding practices!

---

I'd prefer if you do the text printing in the `placement` function itself and call it something like `compare_with_guess`. That way, you don't have to return values and use another if-else block in the caller. Also, the output messages can also be controlled all at one place.

Another way is to use struct like:

```
struct InputNum{
private:
    const int input;
public:
    InputNum(const int num):input(num){};

    int get() const{
        return input;
    }
    bool greater_than(const int target) const {
        return input > target;
    }
    bool less_than(const int target) const {
        return input < target;
    }
    bool equals(const int target) const {
        return input == target;
    }
}
```

---

Use `const` whenever possible.

```
const int winning_num{ generateRandomNumber() };// +1 for {} initialiser syntax.
```

```
void compare_with_guess(const int input, const int guess){ // After making the changes I suggested above.
```

```
bool validateInput(const int input){
```

---

Avoid  `using namespace std;` completely, let alone using it multiple times in the code.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

---

Comment: Thank you for your feedback this helps me very much. The only parts of your answer I do not understand is the line right after public in the struct, and the const outside the function curly brackets. If you could explain those it would be much appreciate.

Comment: @unkn0wn.dev When you pass an `const` or a `const &` etc to a function, you can only call its member functions that are marked `const`. It indicates that calling those functions will not modify the data in the struct. https://ideone.com/qjMS6K this won't compile since `equals` is not a `const` function (sorry I need to lookup the correct term for that) while the `num` is `const&.`

Comment: It is the constructor https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/constructors-cpp?view=vs-2019#init_list_constructors It takes `num` which is `const` since we only read it and then initialises `input` equals to `num`. in the `{}`, you can add a `std::cout` to print both of them.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it better now.

Comment: Could you also explain the advantages of using a struct instead of a class for this instance?

Comment: @unkn0wn.dev https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c2-use-class-if-the-class-has-an-invariant-use-struct-if-the-data-members-can-vary-independently https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rc-class Yeah you're right. Class should be used here.

Comment: Alright thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

Well Your code is working fine but there were some extra code which I have removed and now its like this working same as before.
You can have more simple code if you use using namespace std; at the top of you document.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <random>
using namespace std;
bool validateInput(int input)
{

    if (1 <= input && input <= 100)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int generateRandomNumber()
{
    random_device dev;
    mt19937_64 range(dev());
    uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937_64::result_type> generator(1, 100);
    static_cast<void>(generator(range));
    return static_cast<int>(generator(range));
}

bool placement(int input, int target)
{
    if (input > target)
    {
        cout << "Guess is too high.";
        return false;
    }

    else if (input < target)
    {
        cout << "Guess is too low.";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Guess is correct!";
        return true;
    }
}

int main()
{
    bool end;
    cout << "You have 7 guesses to guess what number I am thinking of between 1 and 100.\n";
    int winning_num{ generateRandomNumber() };
    static int tries{ 1 };
    do
    {
        end=true;
        int num;
        cout << "\nGuess#" << tries << ": Enter a number -> ";
        cin >> num;
        
        if (validateInput(num))
            ;
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (!placement(num, winning_num))
        {
            cout << "\nIncorrect!\n";
            ++tries;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nCorrect!\n";
            exit(0);
        }
        if(tries>7)
        {
            cout<<"\nDo you want to guess more\nnPress y for it and \nPress n for closing\n";
            char guess;
            cin>>guess;
            switch(guess)
            {
                case 'y':
                {
                    cout<<"\nOk Lets go\n";
                    break;
                }
                case 'n':
                {
                    cout<<"\nEnding the program\n";
                    exit(0);
                }
                default:
                {
                    cout<<"\nEnter right choice\n";
                }
                
            }
        }

    }while (end==true);
    cout << "\nYou did not guess the number in the alloted amount of guesses :(\nTry Again!\n";

}
```

You can also ask from user when he want to do more guesses or want to end the program making the program user friendly.

Comment: Please provide a review of the code, not only changes. [answer]